# KDE Panel not fully visible on second screen

Tags: taskbar, ubuntu-18.04, kde-plasma-5

Using Ubuntu 18.04 with KDE installed, I tried to duplicate my taskbar panel. In theory it works, but the lower half is cut off and I can't see why that might be. Clicking in the free area beneat the panel does not open the item where the panel should be (e.g. clicking beneath the dolphin task doesn't open the dolphin window).

[image: Panel on bottom of second Display]

I have tried increasing the height, but that doesn't fix the cut off.
In the Panel Settings, the panel is set to Always Visible and the Panel Alignment is Center.

Moving the panel to another screen edge leads to the same result, it seems.

[image: Panel to the right of second Display]

I am not sure what else I could try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I booted into Windows and back into Ubuntu, now it works. I assume, the reboot did the trick.